# Cursor line and cursor column highlighting "priorities" are inconsistent

Tags: highlight

I have turned on `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` options to highlight cursor line and cursor column, but there is some inconsistency in the behavior. The `CursorLine` highlighting seems to have a lower priority than other syntax highlighting, so the usual syntax highlighting works in the cursor line, but `CursorColumn` seems to have a higher priority, as it cancels the usual syntax highlighting.

How can i change this behavior so that `CursorColumn` highlighting be applied only if there is no corresponding syntax highlighting (like with `CursorLine`)?

Comment: I am afraid, syntax priorities are hard-wired in the source. And it is messy there. That would mean, you'd have to change Vims source